# What's the correct way to write a sqlite.query? (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm struggling to update and query certain entries to my database.
The code above compares the JobNo to the entries in the db and updates the appropriate one however, when trying to only update that particular component the second line throws an error.

```
     long id = db.update(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, contentValues, DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = '" + HCJobNo + "'" , null);
     long id = db.update(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, contentValues,  DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = " + HCJobNo + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COMPONENTTAG + " = " + ComponentTag , null);
```

Simliar when querying to fetch data from the database
It throws and error. This first line works and the other two are incorrect

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, columns, DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = '" + JobNumber + "'", null, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.CONDITION_TABLE, columns, DatabaseHelper.CONDITIONJOBNO + " =? AND " + DatabaseHelper.PARTTAG + " =?", selectionArgs, null, null, null, null);
Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, columns, DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = " + JobNumber + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COMPONENTTAG + " = " + CompTag, null, null, null, null);
```

What's the correct way to write this particular code?

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, columns, DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = " + JobNumber + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COMPONENTTAG + " = " + CompTag, null, null, null, null);
```

Edit:
Cheers

```
long id = db.update(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, contentValues,  DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = '" + HCJobNo + "' AND " + DatabaseHelper.COMPONENTTAG + " = '" + ComponentTag + "'", null);
```

Comment: What error does it throw? How is the table defined?

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Rod (code 1):
answer below fixed it

Comment: accept the answer then, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.COMP_TABLE, columns, DatabaseHelper.HCJOBNO + " = " + JobNumber + " AND " + DatabaseHelper.COMPONENTTAG + " = " + CompTag, null, null, null, null);
```

in this particular string of code at first glance you miss apostrophes around your variables - like you do in your first string.

```
" = '" + JobNumber + "'"
```

or have you already included them into variables' values?

Comment: Sweet thanks! 
This is the correct way of doing it for others, Ill test it out with the queries later!

View main questiion for answer, cheers!!